Heroku router error ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/modules/seat_builder.js")
The error that I am getting, in the Heroku server logs is this:
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/modules/seat_builder.js")
This error is popping up for every single module that I am importing into my seating_controller.js.
Module names

seat_builder.js
seat_editor.js
reservation.js
contingent.js
discount_input_builder.js

I am using Rails 7 with StimulusJS. I have a seating_controller.js that is importing modules from the modules directory in the app/javascript/modules dir (that dir was created by me). Below you can find the code snippets related to my issue:
I believe that here lies my issue this is how my manifest.js file looks now but I tried importing the modules here as well, which did not help anything...
// app/assets/config/manifest.js

//= link_tree ../images
//= link_tree ../../javascript .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js


This is how my application.js file looks like:
// app/javascript/application.js

// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "@rails/actioncable"


This is how my importmap.rb file looks like. I am importing the modules from the modules dir. Double checked the paths they should be correct...
# config/importmap.rb


# frozen_string_literal: true

# Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

pin 'application'
pin '@hotwired/turbo-rails', to: 'turbo.min.js', preload: true
pin '@hotwired/stimulus', to: 'stimulus.min.js'
pin '@hotwired/stimulus-loading', to: 'stimulus-loading.js'
pin_all_from 'app/javascript/controllers', under: 'controllers'
pin_all_from 'app/javascript/modules', under: 'modules'
pin_all_from 'app/javascript/modules/theaters', under: 'modules/theaters'
pin '@rails/actioncable', to: '@rails--actioncable.js' # @7.1.3
pin '@rails/actioncable', to: 'actioncable.esm.js'
pin_all_from 'app/javascript/channels', under: 'channels'


Finally here is my seating_controller.js. For simplicity I am showing only the import paths as the actual code doesn't seem to have any issues...
// app/javascript/controllers/seating_controller.js

import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";
import SeatBuilder from "../modules/seat_builder.js";
import SeatEditor from "../modules/seat_editor.js";
import SeatReservation from "../modules/reservation.js";
import Contingent from "../modules/contingent.js";
import DiscountInputBuilder from "../modules/discount_input_builder.js";

// Connects to data-controller="seating"
export default class extends Controller {

  // Rest of the code here

}

Also I am importing other theater modules into the seat_builder.js module:
// app/javascript/modules/seat_builder.js


import DivadloBroadway from "./theaters/divadlo_broadway.js";
import ObecniDum from "./theaters/obecni_dum.js";
import KostelSvatehoMartinaVeZdi from "./theaters/kostel_svateho_martina_ve_zdi.js";

export default class SeatBuilder {

  // Rest of the code here

}

The idea is to keep the concerns separate by having one controller for everything seating related but adding mixins in form of modules. That seems to prove itself useful in development, but production is not happy... I have been banging my head against the wall with this error for ever. To me it seems that path to the assets is always relative to the manifest.js file. Because the ../modules/file_name.js path that I am using in the controller, if used in the manifest file would result in assets/modules/file_name.js but I am not sure where to go from here... It is also worth noting that everything works in development.
I hope this made sense, thank you in advance for your time and patience!

Is "when they pick the vendor of prague ticket portal" a copy/paste error introduced in the question or do you have a syntax error right there?

My apologies. That was a comment I left there for myself and I only partially deleted it in the snippet up top. That is not a syntax error, it is just a not completely deleted comment. I removed it completely now. But to answer your question it is a copy/paste error.

Hi, thank you for your response! I tried that and this is the error I am getting in the console in development after restarting the server:
Failed to register controller: seating (controllers/seating_controller) TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "modules/seat_builder.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

So the issue was in the importmap.rb and with the way I was importing the files.
Here is the corrected code
# importmap.rb

# frozen_string_literal: true

# Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

pin 'application'
pin '@hotwired/turbo-rails', to: 'turbo.min.js', preload: true
pin '@hotwired/stimulus', to: 'stimulus.min.js'
pin '@hotwired/stimulus-loading', to: 'stimulus-loading.js'
pin_all_from 'app/javascript/controllers', under: 'controllers'
pin_all_from 'app/javascript/modules', under: 'modules', to: 'modules'
pin_all_from 'app/javascript/modules/theater', under: 'modules/theater', to: 'modules/theater'
pin '@rails/actioncable', to: '@rails--actioncable.js' # @7.1.3
pin '@rails/actioncable', to: 'actioncable.esm.js'
pin_all_from 'app/javascript/channels', under: 'channels', to: 'channels'

// seating_controller.js

import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";
import SeatBuilder from "modules/seat_builder";
import SeatEditor from "modules/seat_editor";
import SeatReservation from "modules/reservation";
import Contingent from "modules/contingent";
import DiscountInputBuilder from "modules/discount_input_builder";

Thanks to everyone who took the time and added a comment!
